# Making a JSON resource from html input date

Tags: java, html, json, spring, rest

I am trying to input time using HTML,

```
<form action="/createData">
<input type="date" name="startDate" placeholder="Enter Start Date." />
<input type="submit" value="Create" name="createLogin" />
</form>
```

And

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createData")
    String createData(@("startDate") Date startDate, Model model) {
          String url = "http://localhost:9090/server/create";
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          json.put("startDate", startDate.toString());
          Client client = new Client();
          WebResource resource = client.resource(url);
          ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, json.toString());
          response.getEntity(String.class);
          return "dateAdded";
```

I am not trying to get a response, and only want to save info to the server's SQL database.

However, I am getting parsing errors.

My resource receive server looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(String server) throws JSONException, BarsException, IOException, ParseException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(server);
        SimpleDateFormat originalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String StartDate = originalDateFormat
        dates.setStartDate(StartDate);
        billRepo.save(billing);
        JSONObject op = new JSONObject();
        return Response.status(200).entity(op.toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

I hope you'll understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please also provide the error  message

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you need to @Consumes(MediaType.MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE) since posting via forms is usually sent as urlencoded form.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my answers using your comments. thank you.

here is my working code for other's reference.

```
JSONObject jsonCreate = new JSONObject(server);
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

String stringStartDate = jsonCreate.getString("startDate");
String stringEndDate = jsonCreate.getString("endDate");

LocalDate localStartDate = LocalDate.parse(stringStartDate, format);
LocalDate localEndDate = LocalDate.parse(stringEndDate, format);

java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localStartDate);
java.sql.Date sqlEndDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localEndDate);

Billing bill = new Billing(sqlStartDate, sqlEndDate);
billRepo.save(bill);
```

again thank you for your answers! cheers!

however, this code uses too much conversion.